# Is there any way to assign stylesheets to whole sets of pages using is_page( )

Tags: conditional-tags

The code below allow me to use a different CSS style to any page I declare

```
<body<?php if ( is_page(array('page1', 'page2', 'page3'))) {
echo ' class="myclass" '; } ?>>
```

for example I can use this css to page1 , page2 and page3:

```
.myclass #content { background-color: #123456; }
.myclass #content p { color: #987654; }
```

However I don't know how to use this with every page in one certain path e.g. path /products
. Let's say I have have about 30 pages under the path:
mysite.com/products/somepage1  --> somepage2, somepage3, ... somepage30

So I have to include every page in the code above and even worst, any time I add a new page I have to include it to the code.

Any chance to have a simple way to add all the pages(and new pages) in one certain path?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you're using parent page "photos" as a path.

It's good practice (and required by WordPress Theme Guidelines) to use `body_class()` function for output different classes, based on current page or post. Just insert this function in your theme.

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
```

This function will add `parent-pageid-(id)` class on every child page, cause every child page of "photos" will share same `parent-pageid-(id)` class you can easily add specific styling to them.

```
.parent-pageid-(id-of-photos-page) #content {
     /** Put your style here */
}
.parent-pageid-(id-of-photos-page) #content p {
    /** Style for paragraph tag */
}
```

Comment: I use wp-ecommerce and I would like to use an different css style in every page under mysite.com/products-page to change a few background images of my theme

Comment: Didn't use WP e-Commerce, so not sure how it creates products page. Add `body_class()` template tag to `<body>` and then using Chrome dev tools or firebug inspect what classes are added for those specific pages.

Comment: not sure if I did it right, but I got this: class="page page-id-79 page-parent page-template-default logged-in admin-bar wpsc"

Comment: Yes you did it right, but this is css classes for parent page, to target this page you can use this class e.g. - `.page-id-79 #content` and all its children pages would share same `.parent-pageid-79` class

Comment: Unfortunally it didn't work, I tried to change a background image but no lucky:    .page-id-79 #page-top { background-image: url("img/page_top2.jpg") no-repeat; }

Comment: Are you sure that you didn't do the CSS wrong? @DavidCibin

Comment: I'm still learning but I think I did it right. If you don't mind you can check it out www.jmmoveisedesign.com.br/produtos yo'll see an white image on the background because that first code above however if try another page under path /produtos like /produtos/checkout or /produtos/conta the image will be the original wood

Comment: You didn't inserted `body_class()` template tag in you theme, please insert it and then I can do test.

Comment: Actally I did, but I was testing local. Anyway, I add the code you can try now

Comment: Any chance you take a look again? I tried a lot of different things, but I can't find how to customize it

Comment: Can you inset `body_class()` tag properly? I checked your site and it's add after body tag wrapped in span. If you do so I'll get automatically generated class on `produtos/checkout/` based on parent page, now it's `parent-pageid-79`

Comment: I hope I inserted it correctly now

Answer (score 0):

There's a wealth of options to choose from, actually, so there's bound to be a function that fits your needs.

We would need more detail about how you're generating pages you mention, but assuming you're talking about custom post types, adding this instead of is_page will have the desired effect in all pages, including future ones:

```
is_singular('wpsc-product');
```

If this isn't quite what you're looking for, check out the list of available functions [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_singular#Related).

Comment: This is_singular didn't work, so this is not an example is exactly what I'm trying to do: I use wp-ecommerce and I would like to use an different css style in every page under mysite.com/products-page to change a few background images of my theme

Comment: I've edited the answer based on the changes you've made to the question, and the fact that you're using WP e-Commerce.

Comment: just to check,I tried this but didn't work:    <body<?php if ( is_singular('wpsc-products')) {
echo ' class="myclass" '; } ?>>